# RDLC Report grouped by month and year in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, report, rdlc, drillthrough

I have a ASP.NET MVC 4 app with an ASP.NET Web Form with a `ReportViewer` control. I'm using Entity Framework.

I want to display a table with Orders(id, date_add, name,quantity, price)

```
1 | 2011-12-08 | apples  | 4  | 0.99

2 | 2012-01-07 | oranges | 20 | 1.39

4 | 2012-03-04 | plumes  | 80 | 1.59

5 | 2012-05-01 | apples  | 15 | 0.89

6 | 2012-05-03 | pears   | 10 | 1.29

7 | 2012-05-09 | oranges | 18 | 1.49
```

I want my report to look like this:

```
December - Sum(price for dec 2011)

1 | 2011-12-08 | apples  | 4  | 0.99

2011 - Sum(price for 2011)

January - Sum(price for jan 2012)

2 | 2012-01-07 | oranges | 20 | 1.39

March - Sum(price for mar 2012)

4 | 2012-03-04 | plumes  | 80 | 1.59

May - Sum(price for may 2012)

5 | 2012-05-01 | apples  | 15 | 0.89

6 | 2012-05-03 | pears   | 10 | 1.29

7 | 2012-05-09 | oranges | 18 | 1.49

2012 - Sum(price for 2012)
```

How can it be done using drill-through?

And could the month be collapsed and the year visible (at first run)?

Answer (score 0):

I've made a SP where I extract the Week, Month and Year no. from the *data*_add field.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Orders]         
AS
   SELECT  id_order, data_add, order_name, quantity, price, MONTH(data_add) as Mn, YEAR(data_add) as Ye, DATEPART( wk, data_add) as Week,
   FROM order
RETURN
```

In the report's Tablix, I've grouped 2 times( first by month, then by year).